# Developer environment - how to call/consume other micro services

Tags: java, rest, playframework, docker

**Background**

My Environment - Java, Play2, MySql

I've written 3 stateless Restful Microservices on Play2  -> /S1,/S2,/S3

S1 consumes data from S2 and S3.  So when user hits /S1, that service asynchronously calls /S2, /S3, merges data and returns final json output.  Side note - The services will be shipped eventually as docker images.

For testing in developer environment, I run /s1,/s2,/s3 on ports 9000, 9001 and 9002 respectively. I pickup the port numbers from a config file etc.  I hit the services and everything works fine.  But there is a better way to setup the test env on my developer box correct?  Example - What if I want to run 20 services etc..

So with that said, on production they will be called just like mydomain.com/s1, mydomain.com/s2, mydomain.com/s3 etc.  I want to accomplish this on my developer environment box....I guess there's some reverse proxying involved I would imagine.

**Question**

So the question is, how do I call /S2 and /S3 from within S1 without specifying or using the port number on developer environment.  How are people testing microservices on their local machine?

**Extra Bonus**

Knowing that I'll be shipping my services as docker images, how do I accomplish the same thing with docker containers (each container running one service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (IMO) is to set up your development environment to mirror as closely as possible your production environment. If you want your production application to work with 20 microservices, each running in a separate container, then do that with your development machine. That way, when you deploy to production, you don't have to change from using ports to using hostnames.

The easiest way to set up a large set of microservices in a bunch of different containers is probably with [Fig](http://fig.sh/) or with Docker's upcoming [integrated orchestration tools](http://blog.docker.com/2014/12/docker-announces-orchestration-for-multi-container-distributed-apps/). Since we don't have all the details on what's coming, I'll use Fig. This is a `fig.yml` file for a production server:

```
application:
  image: application-image
  links:
    - service1:service1
    - service2:service2
    - service3:service3
    ...

service1:
  image: service1-image
  ...

service2:
  image: service2-image
  ...

service3:
  image: service3-image
  ...
```

This abbreviated `fig.yml` file will set up links between the application and all the services so that in your code, you can refer to them via hostname `service1`, `service2`, etc.

For development purposes, there's lots more that needs to go in here: for each of the services you'll probably want to mount a directory in which to edit the code, you may want to expose some ports so you can test services directly, etc. But at it's core, the development environment is the same as the production environment.

It does sound like a lot, but a tool like Fig makes it really easy to configure and run your application. If you don't want to use Fig, then you can do the same with Docker commands - the key is the links between containers. I'd probably create a script to set things up for both the production and development environments.

Comment: You referred to the link as a hostname. Is it safe to assume that in production this will be resolved by DNS but in development it is resolved via link?

Comment: No, in both development & production they will be resolved via link. When you link Docker containers, Docker creates an entry in `/etc/hosts` assigning a name to that linked container so you can refer to it directly.

Comment: I was assuming that in development these containers would run on the same machine but in production they will be on separate machine and potentially running as a cluster.

Comment: That makes sense - I was assuming that they would be running on the same host in both dev & production. I'm afraid I don't have much experience with deploying apps on multiple machines, although it shouldn't be *too* difficult to set up your containers so that they use DNS for name resolution in production.

Comment: yeah.. the trick would be to use the same names that are used in the links. I assume you can use dots in the names of the links, i.e. service.domain

Answer (score 0):

> Example - What if I want to run 20 services etc

docker will create entries in etc hosts file for each of the linked containers using their alias. So If you link a lot of containers you can just address them using their alias name. Do not map the port to a public port using -p 9000:9000. This way all your services can be on port 9000 on their own docker host which can be looked up from /etc/hosts

> "how do I accomplish the same thing..."

This is an open question, here is some [good reading](http://progrium.com/blog/2014/07/29/understanding-modern-service-discovery-with-docker/) on the topic. [SkyDock](https://github.com/crosbymichael/skydock) and SkyDNS get you most of the way of service discovery and [weave](https://github.com/zettio/weave/) gets you easy to use networking between remote docker containers. I have not seen a better end-to-end solution yet although there may be some out there.

Comment: What if you have an app container, service container, and want to dynamically call http://service:port/api/call.json from the app container? Restrictions: no hardcoded IP or port in my code, as you suggest. I can get the IP from /etc/hosts but not the PORT for the service.

Comment: Your service should be listening well known port, as each container gets its own IP (at least in bridged networking) there is no port collision. If you need to have variable ports then you need a more heavy weight service discovery solution like zookeeper.

Comment: Ok, I have hardcoded the service port, but ENV only shows internal IP's on Docker Swarm. My javascript on a PHP container front-end page cannot use that internal IP, so Consul, Etcd seem useless. Can I pass public IP?

Comment: With public ports you pretty much have to use reverse proxies or manage the random port assignment yourself somehow. Rancher.io provides reverse proxy through its load balancers. There are potentially other reverse proxy solutions as well.

Comment: Ah, bummer. Rackspace doesn't support Rancher due to AppArmor not allowing `--privileged` flag.